# Sequence-to-sequence autoencoder input dimension error in Keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

I'm currently working on a Keras sequence-to-sequence autoencoder with data that has a variable timestep length. The data is currently a list of 54 2D-NumPy arrays. Every array has 12 columns but a variable amount of rows. Keras wants input with shape(54, None, 12) but this is not possible with NumPy.

When trying to fit the function, I get the following error:

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the 
size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 54 arrays: 
[array([[-528.38763428,  135.60964966,  113.43732452, ...
```

When trying to feed the data as a NumPy array instead of a list, it generates the following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected input_14 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (54, 1)
```

Can someone help me with fixing this, I have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: Can you please share the input and model input layer?

Comment: The input layer is as follows:
inputs = Input(shape=(None, 12))

How exactly do you want me to give you the input? Copy pasting isn't really an option